# How to find the correct path for images using sweetalert2 and vue2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, path, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm working on a project and trying to make a modal with an image within, but the image never appears. I have tryed every posible path and some functions like fs but nothing. The structure of my proyect is this:

```
-main
    |-dist
    |-node_modules(sweetalert2 ubication)
    |-public
    |-src
         |-App.vue
         |-main.js
         |-assets -(where is the image "img.jpg")
         |- ...
         |- ...
         |-views
                |-...(some views.vue)
                |-myView.vue
```

At myView.vue I use $swal.fire and try to insert an image using imageUrl but only gets the alt for the image. How could I add this image to the sweetalert2 modal, or at least how could I know what is the path from where sweetalert2 modal is loading.
This is my options for the sweetalert2 modal with the last path I tried:

```js
var options = {
        title: "¿Seguro que quiere eliminar el activo?",
        imageUrl: "../assets/papelera.jpg",
        imageHeight: "100px",
        imageAlt: "papelera",
        text: "Una vez eliminado desaparecerá el presupuesto que haya realizado sobre ese activo.",
        showConfirmButton: true,
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
        confirmButtonText: "Borrar"
      };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A second after I ask the question I have found the answe, Using `require(../assets/img.jpg)` it works fine.